# Separate equation $\sin3x\mathrm{d}x+2y(\cos3x)^3\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find solution by using separable equation $$\sin3x\mathrm{d}x +2y\cos^33x\mathrm{d}y=0$$

So far I got this

$$\frac{\sin3x}{\cos^33x}\mathrm{d}x + 2y\mathrm{d}y = 0$$

$$ 2y\mathrm{d}y = -\frac{\sin3x}{\cos^33x}\mathrm{d}x$$

Integrate both sides

$$\int2y\mathrm{d}y = -\int\frac{\sin3x}{\cos^33x}\mathrm{d}x$$

let  $U=\sin3x$ and $\mathrm{d}u=3\cos3x \mathrm{d}x$

$$y^2=\int\frac{u}{(\mathrm{d}u)^3}$$

Now $\mathrm{d}u$ has become a denominator and cubed, not sure how to proceed, thanks in advance

Comment: Rather try $u=\cos 3x$. As there is only one $dx$, there can only be one $du$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:$$y^2=-\int\frac{\sin3x}{\cos^33x}dx$$
$$\cos 3x=u\Rightarrow-3\sin3xdx=du\Rightarrow-\sin3xdx=\frac{du}{3}$$
$$y^2=\int\frac{du}{3u^3}$$

Comment: $du/(9u^2)=du/(9\cos^6(3x))$, which is the wrong power. Why did you start with the third power at all? Why not start with the result, i.e., use $u=1/\cos^2(3x)$?

Comment: I edit my answer

Comment: Your first error is in computing $-\sin3x\,dx$.

Comment: Dear LutzL  I think now is correct. Thank you.